# Add and Updates not working for attributes in ArcGIS Runtime for .Net

Tags: arcgis-10.3, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

Environment:

- ArcGIS Runtime for .NET 10.2.7
- ArcGIS Server 10.3.1
- Map Service with Feature Access enabled (Create, Read, Update)
- Postgres database underneath

  ```
  ServiceFeatureTable reportLayer = await ServiceFeatureTable.OpenAsync(new Uri("http://localhost/arcgis/rest/services/MyMapService/FeatureServer/4"));
  var testFeature = reportLayer.CreateNew(); //new GeodatabaseFeature(reportLayer.Schema);
  testFeature.Attributes["a_commodity_group"] = "fake";

  var addedReportOIDs = await reportLayer.AddAsync(testFeature);
  var editResult = await reportLayer.ApplyEditsAsync();
  ```

I've done the CreateNew() as well as creating a new GeodatabaseFeature as described in the documents here:

https://developers.arcgis.com/net/desktop/guide/edit-features.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_2A4C0222216A448C9CBAFCD0F75A21F6

I've tried Adding and Updating features. The "a_commodity_group" attribute is exactly how I see it spelled in the rest endpoint and is a Text/varchar field in the database underneath

I'm seeing none of my attributes come through. (example, the "fake" value that I've put in here)

ArcGIS Server Log (at "Info" level)

> FINE Mar 28, 2016, 8:59:46 PM GraphicFeatureServer::HandleRESTRequest
>
> ### inputJSON = {"rollbackOnFailure":true,"adds":[{"attributes":{"objectid":-10}}]}

Inspecting client traffic from Telerik's Fiddler:

As you can see, the request is totally wrong in that it doesn't have any other attributes going in.
[image]

Manually adding features through "ApplyEdits" in the REST endpoint worked. 
[image]

Info from ArcGIS Server logs (the attributes come in correctly here):

> GraphicFeatureServer::HandleRESTRequest ## inputJSON =
>   {"adds":[{"attributes":{"objectid":405,"a_commodity_group":"fake"}}],"rollbackOnFailure":true}

I don't see any known issues with this in the ArcGIS Runtime.
I'm considering writing my own REST api as the workaround right now since I can't get this to work.

It's quite possible that I'm making a totally wrong assumption in how I'm using the API, but I haven't seen many examples for adding features to a connected service. I'll double check the full .net runtime sdk pdf document and see if I'm doing anything wrong, too.

**Update:**
I also noticed that `DeleteAsync` doesn't work unless I `layer.QueryAsync` the features first. Probably has something to do with some local cache in the `ServiceFeatureTable` layer object. Before I was querying objectids using the `ExecuteObjectIdsQueryAsync()` method on a `QueryTask` object.

Comment: I'll probably open a dev support ticket in the next few days and have something useful to share in the next week or so.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem adding features, the geometry went in but no attributes.  I fixed it for my code by adding the OutFields to the ServiceFeatureTable in the xaml file:

```
        <esri:ServiceFeatureTable 
                 ServiceUri="http://..."  OutFields="USER_NAME,EXTRACTION_ID"/>
        </esri:FeatureLayer.FeatureTable>
```

Works fine now.  I guess the example at https://developers.arcgis.com/net/desktop/guide/edit-features.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_2A4C0222216A448C9CBAFCD0F75A21F6 doesn't show the xaml.